# Play mp3 file based upon name of image

Tags: javascript, php, audio

Lets start of with the code.

```
$dir = "..//images/alphabet/";


$dirname = $dir;
$images = glob($dirname."*.{jpg,gif,png}",GLOB_BRACE);

foreach($images as $image) {
    
    $soundToPlay = explode (".",$image);
    $soundToPlay1 = $soundToPlay[2];
    $soundToPlay2 = explode ("/",$soundToPlay1);
    $soundToPlay3 = $soundToPlay2[4];
        
    echo '<input type="image" value="Play" height="300px" src="'.$image.'"
    onclick="bleep.play()";></input>';
    
    echo $soundToPlay3;
    echo "
    <script>
    var bleep = new Audio();
    bleep.src = 'http://webaddress/pages/bleep.mp3';
    </script>
         ";

}
?>
```

What im trying to do is

1. search a folder
   2.display all images
2. click image to play .mp3 with image name

for example

click image named a.png and play mp3 named a.mp3
click image named b.png and play mp3 named b.mp3

The above code shows all images i have test echo $soundToPlay3 just to check i get the correct file name and i do.

it stops working if i try and replace

`bleep.src = 'http://webaddress/pages/bleep.mp3';`

with

`bleep.src = 'http://webaddress/pages/$soundToPlay3.mp3';`

This has to be simple.
I have so many imaged i cant do it all by hand, one by one.

i assume its something to do with mixing javascript and php. I have been out of touch for a while.

Thanks in advance
Daz

Comment: Check the output to see what is being assigned to bleep.src

Comment: You can not do this by having one _static_ audio object, you need to set the source of that dynamically, based on what image was actually clicked. So you will need to replace `onclick="bleep.play()"` with a custom function first of all, that can then do the dynamic stuff. The name of the mp3 file to play could either be put into a custom data attribute on the image button, so you can read it from there, or you could just read the image `src`, and manipulate that accordingly (string replacement, or regex.)

Comment: "Stops working" is pretty broad. What have you tried to check what really happens?

Comment: Nico....when i replace the word bleep to the $soundToPlay3 i  have no noise.   Broe could you suggest one......im not as good as your giving me credit for

Comment: @John alphabet.php:22 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources.

Comment: @user2826526 thats not the output. That is an error log.

Comment: @John wheres the output please.

Comment: @CBroe any chance you could explain a little more. Im new to javascript and ive had a 10 year break from PHP and even then im sell tought.

Answer (score 0):

As @CBroe said i needed to swap

`onclick="bleep.play()"`

for another function.

After a bit of googling etc i found a function from this page
https://www.codespeedy.com/change-html5-audio-player-src-file-in-javascript/

And here is the working code

Thanks to everyone!

```
<audio id="my-audio" >
<source src="http://website/pages/bleep.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
  
   function cs_change_music(music)
   {
      
     document.getElementById("my-audio").pause();
     document.getElementById("my-audio").setAttribute('src', music);
     document.getElementById("my-audio").load();
     document.getElementById("my-audio").play();
   }
</script>

<?php
$sound=$_GET['sound'];
$dir = "..//images/alphabet/";

$dirname = $dir;
$images = glob($dirname."*.{jpg,gif,png}",GLOB_BRACE);

foreach($images as $image) {
    
    $soundToPlay = explode (".",$image);
    $soundToPlay1 = $soundToPlay[2];
    $soundToPlay2 = explode ("/",$soundToPlay1);
    $soundToPlay3 = $soundToPlay2[4];
        

    echo '<input type="image" value="Play" alt="new" height="200px" src="'.$image.'" 
        onclick="cs_change_music(\'http://website/sounds/'.$soundToPlay3.'.mp3\');"></input>
        ';
  
}
?>
```